# C# Search Active Directory error

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am pretty new to using C# and this is my second time using it with active directory. I keep getting the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Below is my code. I know that my null reference is in the line `var result = searcher.FindOne();` I am unsure of what I need to do to fix this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> userList = new List<string>();

        try
        {


            string[] newUsers = { List of users is here ex: jsmith@xyz.com, bsmith@xyz.com, ... };

            PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xyz.com");
            UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
            PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();

            foreach (string x in newUsers)
            {
                searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(anr={0}))", x);

                var result = searcher.FindOne();

                userList.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", result.Properties["DisplayName"][0].ToString(), result.Properties["Company"][0].ToString()));

                search.Dispose();
            }

            foreach(string y in userList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(y);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(file location, userList);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you tried debugging at all?  That's a pretty surefire way to find out which line of code the exception is occurring on.

Comment: You are not checking for search.FindOne() returning null, which it may do if one of those user names in your array is incorrectly specified.

Comment: I know that it is my var result = searcher.FindOne(); that is null I am just not sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're declaring `PrincipalSearcher` and `DirectorySearcher`, yet you're only populating the `PrincipalSearcher` with `UserPrincipal` object.

```
...
UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);
...
```

However, your `DirectorySearcher` object `searcher` is empty.

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
```

In `foreach` loop you're searching for one user using `DirectorySearcher` object not `PrincipalSearcher`:

```
var result = searcher.FindOne();
```

The above line will always return `null`. You need to populate `DirectorySearcher`.

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(/*need a DirectoryEntry*/);
```

I would suggest you take full advantage of `UserPrincipal` class. It seems that you want to search for users in `Active Directory` and you know their `UserPrincipal` names.

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{
    string [] newUsers; //need to declare list of new users
    foreach (string user in newUsers)
    {
       using (UserPrincipal newUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, user))
       {
          if (newUser != null)
          {
            //do what you need to do
            //newUser will contain all info on a particular user
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As several commenters have noted, your code is not handling the situation where no user is found by `DirectorySearcher.FindOne` - and, [as noted in the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findone(v=vs.110).aspx), `FindOne` returns `null` if no user is found:

> If more than one entry is found during the search, only the first entry is returned. If no entries are found to match the search criteria, a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) is returned.

So you'll need to handle the case where the user you're looking for isn't there:

```
    foreach (string x in newUsers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("looking for user {0}", x);
        searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(anr={0}))", x);
        var result = searcher.FindOne();
        if (result == null)
        {
            userList.Add(String.Format("user {0} not found!", x));
        }
        else 
        {
            userList.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", result.Properties["DisplayName"][0].ToString(), result.Properties["Company"][0].ToString()));
        }
        search.Dispose();
    }
```